# Transferring Files using PSFTP and Powershell

Tags: powershell, psftp

I have a working powershell script that invokes psftp.exe and lets me transfer files from my local computer to my server in the cloud successfully. Everything works fine except for an error (does not preempt anything as far as i know) is being flashed on my powershell ISE Screen.

```
PS D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src> D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\mypowershell.ps1
.\psftp.exe : Looking up host "remoteserver"
At D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\mypowershell.ps1:30 char:20
+ ... expression (.\psftp.exe 'remoteserver' -l 'ubuntu' -i key.ppk ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Looking up host "remoteserver":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Connecting to remoteserver port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 87:4d:50:8d:09:25:40:78:c2:7b:5c:ef:12:8e:57:7c
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Reading private key file "key.ppk"
Using username "ubuntu".
Offered public key
Offer of public key accepted
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Sent public key signature
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Started a shell/command
Sent EOF message
Server sent command exit status 0
Disconnected: All channels closed
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.
At D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\mypowershell.ps1:30 char:19
+ ... -expression (.\psftp.exe 'remoteserver' -l 'ubuntu' -i key.ppk ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Please note that I replaced my server IP with the word remoteserver and my remote PC's IP with remotePC for my security purpose. The powershell I am using contains the following codes:

```
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
$props = Get-Content D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\branch.txt
$BranchName = $props | select-string 'BranchName' | %{$_.line.split('=')}
$Branch = $BranchName[1]
$datetime2 = get-date -format yyyyMMdd
$datetime = get-date
$Logfile = "D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\logs\$Branch-$datetime2-chronos.log"
Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}
if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName remotePC -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)){ LogWrite "$datetime Biometric Device is turned off!"  }else{ LogWrite "$datetime Biometric Device is turned on!"}
$startdate = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$enddate = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
for($i=1;$i -le 1000;$i++){
       $number +="$i,"       
     }
$numlength = $number.Length-1
$x = invoke-webrequest -Uri 'http://remotePC/form/Download?uid=$number"&"sdate=$startdate"&"edate=$enddate' -OutFile D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\logs\$Branch-$datetime2.dat -PassThru
if($x.StatusCode -eq 200){
    LogWrite "$datetime Timesheet successfully retrieved. Response code: $($x.StatusCode)"
}else{
    LogWrite "$datetime Error retrieving timesheet. Response code: $($x.StatusCode)"
}
#invoke-expression .\psftp.exe -i key.ppk ubuntu@remoteserver -be b sftpcommands.txt > D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\logs\sftp-log.log 2>$null
#Write-Host "done"

invoke-expression (.\psftp.exe 'remoteserver' -l 'ubuntu' -i key.ppk -v -b 'sftpcommands.txt' > 'D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\logs\sftp-log.log') 2> $null
```

Comment: Apparently psftp writes colored text to stderr and naive powershell ISE treats it as an error. Redirect stderr to stdin (google for examples in PS) or disable colors using a command line switch of psftp.

Comment: Can you give me an idea how redirect stderr to stdin?

Comment: Personally I would use `cmd /c "2>&1" psftp ...........` but you can find other examples by googling.